# Close WPF application until the function completed

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

i am newbie in C#, i am mainly developed .net application with VB.

i had developed .net WPF application to connect microsoft cognitive service to get image description and save to sql server.

because i will run it as a scheduled task, therefore i want it close automatically after finished the process.

the application can work properly to get the image description and update table.

but it will close immediately without start the process if i add the close application function.

may i know how can the application wait the process finish before close the application?

Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.IO;
using Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision;
using Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision.Contract;

using System.Diagnostics;


namespace TagPhotoScheduler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Boolean Finished = false;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ReadFile();    
            CloseApp();
        }

        public void CloseApp()
        {
            //close application after run
            if (Finished == true)
            {                
                Application.Current.Shutdown();
                //this.Close();
            }
        }

        public void ReadFile()
        {
            DataClassesTagPhotoDataContext dc = new DataClassesTagPhotoDataContext();

            var query = from qPhoto in dc.db_PhotoLibrary_Photos
                        where qPhoto.ML_Processed == false
                        select qPhoto;

            foreach (var q in query)
            {    
                string pFileName = string.Empty;
                string photoURL = string.Empty;

                pFileName = q.PhotoID + "." + q.FileType;

                _status.Text += pFileName + " | ";

                photoURL = "https://example.com/storage/";

                if (q.ProjectID == null || q.ProjectID == 0)
                {
                    GetTag(q.PhotoID, photoURL + pFileName);

                    _status.Text += photoURL + pFileName + " \n";
                }
                else //had projectid
                {                        
                    photoURL +=  q.ProjectID + "/";

                    if (q.AlbumID == null || q.AlbumID == 0)
                    {
                        //photoURL += "/" + q.AlbumID + "/";
                        GetTag(q.PhotoID, photoURL + pFileName);
                        _status.Text += photoURL + pFileName + " \n";

                    }
                    else //albumid
                    {
                        photoURL +=  q.AlbumID + "/";
                        GetTag(q.PhotoID, photoURL + pFileName);
                        _status.Text += photoURL + pFileName + " \n";
                    }                            
                }    
            }
            //Finished = true;
            _status.Text += "\n\nFinished";
        }    

        public async void GetTag(int PhotoID, string URL)
        {
            VisionServiceClient VisionServiceClient = new VisionServiceClient("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "https://eastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0");

            DataClassesTagPhotoDataContext dc = new DataClassesTagPhotoDataContext();

            try
            {

                AnalysisResult analysisResult = await VisionServiceClient.DescribeAsync(URL, 3);

                if (analysisResult.Description != null)
                {    
                    foreach (var tag in analysisResult.Description.Tags)
                    {
                        tags += tag + ", ";

                        string QueryAnalysis = string.Empty;

                        db_PhotoLibrary_Photo_Tag newQ = new db_PhotoLibrary_Photo_Tag();
                        newQ.TagOn = DateTime.Now;
                        newQ.TagBy = 0;
                        newQ.PhotoID = PhotoID;
                        newQ.ML_Tag = true;
                        newQ.TagType = 0;
                        newQ.TagName = tag;
                        dc.db_PhotoLibrary_Photo_Tags.InsertOnSubmit(newQ);
                        dc.SubmitChanges();    

                        db_PhotoLibrary_Photo result = (from p in dc.db_PhotoLibrary_Photos
                                                        where p.PhotoID == PhotoID
                                                        select p).SingleOrDefault();    
                        result.ML_Processed = true;    
                        dc.SubmitChanges();    
                    }    
                    _status.Text = tags;
                }
            }
            catch { }    
        }    
    }    
}
```

Finally, i change it to console application and it can do my job.

Comment: It appears you're using `async void GetTag` in a fire-and-forget manner and this looks like the core problem here. You should probably make it `async Task` and then track all pending tasks to completion before exiting the app. Misusing `async void` is a common pitfall and is widely covered here on SO.

Comment: `ReadFile` and `GetTag` needs to be `async Task`. Then take `ReadFile` and `CloseApp` out of the constructor. Then your `MainWindow` can expose an initialization task as [seen here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html). That task will represent the file access and will be awaited in your composition root, which for WPF is typically `App.xaml.cs`. Finally when the initialization task completes the app can exit.

Comment: Another consideration is why you're using WPF at all when it doesn't look like you need the UI. With a console app you don't have any of the complications of an async constructor and could easily just `await ReadFile` and then exit.

Comment: Thanks JSteward. i changed it to console application and it can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the ReadFile function with a task and use continuation:

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Task.Run(ReadFile).ContinueWith(CloseApp);    

        }
```

Are you even sure that this needs to be WPF app? Console would not do the job?

Comment: Thanks. i changed it to console application and it can do the job.